# Transfer files that are new or edited in the last 24 hours

Tags: python, time, file-transfer

I am trying to have files from a certain folder be transferred to a destination folder if it is a new file or a file that has been edited in the last 24 hours. Specifically, the `transferFiles()` function is the part that needs help. I'm still pretty new to Python, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog
import os
import time
import shutil
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import glob



class ParentWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        #title for GUI window
        self.master.title("File Transfer")
        
        #Button to select files from source directory
        self.sourceDir_btn = Button(text="Select Source", width=20, command=self.sourceDir)
        #Positions source button in GUI with tkinter grid()
        self.sourceDir_btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(20,10), pady=(30, 0))
        #Positions source directory selection
        self.source_dir = Entry(width=75)
        #positions entry in GUI using tkinter grid()
        self.source_dir.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(20,10), pady=(30, 0))

        #Creates button to select destination of files from destination directory
        self.destDir_btn = Button(text="Select Destination", width=20, command=self.destDir)
        #Positions destination button in GUI using tkinter grid() on the next row
        self.destDir_btn.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=(20, 10), pady=(15, 10))

        #Creates entry for destiantion directory selection
        self.destination_dir = Entry(width=75)
        #Postitions entry in GUI using tkinter grid() padx and pady
        self.destination_dir.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=(20, 10), pady=(15, 10))

        #creates button to transfer files
        self.transfer_btn = Button(text="Transfer Files", width=20, command = self.transferFiles)
        #positions transfer files button
        self.transfer_btn.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(200,0), pady=(0,15))

        #creates an exit button
        self.exit_btn = Button(text= "Exit", width=20, comman=self.exit_program)
        #positions the exit button
        self.exit_btn.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=(10, 40), pady=(0, 15))
        
    
    def sourceDir(self):
        selectSourceDir = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()
        #The .delete will clear the content that is inserted in the entry widget
        self.source_dir.delete(0, END)
        #The .insert method will insert the user selection to the source_dir Entry
        self.source_dir.insert(0, selectSourceDir)
        

    def destDir(self):
        selectDestDir = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()
        #The .delete will clear the content that is inserted in the entry widget
        self.destination_dir.delete(0, END)
        #The insert method will insert the user selection to the destination_dir Entry widget
        self.destination_dir.insert(0,selectDestDir)
        

    def transferFiles(self):
        
        source = self.source_dir.get()

        destination = self.destination_dir.get()

        source_files = os.listdir(source)

        source_files.get(source_files) 

        source_files_return = os.stat(source_files.get())

        for i in source_files:
            modifyDate = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(source_files_return))
            todaysDate = datetime.today()

            modifyDateLimit = modifyDate + timedelta(days = 1)

            if modifyDateLimit > todaysDate:
                shutil.move(source + '/' + i, destination.get())
                print(i + ' was sucessfully transferred.')

        
        
            
    
    def exit_program(self):
        root.destroy()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    App = ParentWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\buffy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\buffy\myRepository\Python-Projects\FileTransferAssignment\file_transfer.py", line 73, in transferFiles
    source_files.get(source_files)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0):

source_files is just a regular list which does not have a get() method. I am not sure what you were trying to do with `source_files.get(source_files)`. But if you want to get a list of stats, do

```
[os.stat(f) for f in source_files]
```

which is a list comprehension shorthand to iterate through the list of source files and call os.stat() on each element.